# Why does onActivityResult return, but I am getting the correct requestCode?

Tags: android, android-intent, null, onactivityresult

I'm building an application where the first Activity starts another one by `startActivityByResult`. After some setting is done, I need to send the setting result back.

So I override the second Activity's `onPause()` method, I get the intent, `putExra`, and send it back through `setResult()`.

Back to the first Activity. `onActivityResult` has definitely been called. I got the resultCode set before, but the intent data is null. I can't figure out what's wrong.

Here's my code:

The first Activity

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.e("page1", requestCode + "_");
    Log.e("page1", resultCode + "_");
    Log.e("page1", (data == null) + "_");
    // if ((requestCode == 1) && (data != null)) {
    if (data != null) {
        String size = data.getStringExtra("size");
        Log.e("switch", size + "_");
        switch (size.charAt(0)) {
        case '1': {
            text.setTextSize(10);
        }
            break;
        case '2': {
            text.setTextSize(20);
        }
            break;
        case '3': {
            text.setTextSize(30);
        }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

My second Activity

```
    @Override
protected void onPause() {

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Log.e("prefs", (intent == null) + "_");
    intent.putExtra("size", size);
    setResult(3, intent);
    super.onPause();
}
```

I've tested in LogCat. In the second Activity. The intent about to be sent is definitely not null. But when it goes to the first Activity. Null just returned. This is driving me really crazy.

Comment: can you tell why you are setting result in onpause..

Comment: check my answer below to your question. And check as answer if it works for you

Comment: @BharatSharma the reason is the second Activity is a PreferenceActivity, where some preferences are made. if i make a listener or something like it, everytime i make any modificaiton, i have to send back an intent which i think it's tedious. so i am thinking about a way that after the ueser finishes all the settings, and press "back", at this point the secoend Activity sends back the result. but one more thing to make sure is the result should arrive before the the first Activity restarts.

Comment: @BharatSharma since the life-cycle is "Activity2 onPause() --> Activity1 onRestart() --> Activity1 onStart() --> Activity2 onStop() --> Activity2 onDestroy()" i decide to set result in onPause()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this.
you want to finish your activity in all the cases in pause manually and in back press automatically so it will be better to save your intent data in onDestroy

```
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        intent.putExtra("size", size);
        setResult(3, intent);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
```

Comment: i tried, but it doesn't work. first of all, super.onPause() must be called, or else an exception like SuperClassNotCalledException() will be thrown. and then i create a new intent in onPause(). again there is null returned in the first Activity. God! i still can uderstand. if the Intent data is null, how come it returns a correct requestCode. really makes me wanna smash my pc.

Comment: it will be better if you set result on destroy.

Comment: no, i tried, failed. and according to the Activity's life-cycle, the onDestroyed() of the previous Activity to be closed will be called after the opening Activity's onCreate(). so it doesn't work...

Comment: onDestroyed will be call whenever you call finish() method.. you can only able to call finish when your activity have already created. just now i have check previously it was returning null and when i changed that code it was working fine. where it is crashing.

Comment: oh yeah! brilliant! it works great! thank you!!!!!!! my first question here got fixxed!

Answer (score 1):

Problem with your code is in `String size = data.getStringExtra("size");` this line.
You should change it with `String size = data.getExtras.getString("size");`

In your first activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

And in your second activity make a button called `SAVE` and in its listener;

```
        Intent result = new Intent();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

        bundle.putString("keyName", "KeyValue");

        result.putExtras(bundle);
        setResult(RESULT_OK,result);
        finish();
```

And again in your first activity's `onActivityresult` method:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE){
            Log.d("Activity Result", data.getExtras.getString("keyName");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, my problem is the intent data is null. please ignore the way i retrieve the String from the intent. i used make a button to send back intent. and it works pretty well. but in this application, my second Activity is a PreferenceActivity, so i don't want to make too many components. the functionaliy i need is when i exit the second Activity with settings done, the intent will be sent. but as i explain. the first Activity's onActivityResult works, but no intent received. i don't get it.